# Online Predictions for Keras model via API

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, prediction

I have an image classification deep learning CNN model (.h5 file) trained using Keras and Tensorflow 2 that I want to use online for predictions. I want an API that takes the single input image over HTTP and responds with the predicted class labels using the trained model. Is there an API provided by Keras or Tensorflow to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two basic options:

- Use [TensorFlow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker) - it provides ready-to-go REST API server, the only thing that you need to do is to convert your model to .pb format.
- Write your own simple REST server (on Flask, for example) which will call `model.predict()` on the inputs (that approach may be easier to start with, but it will be hard to scale/optimize for heavy load.

Comment: Thanks, the second option will also work since I am working on a personal project but if TensorFlow Serving does not has many prerequisites, I would go with that :-)